# How to get and load nested JSON values into Tableview Objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

Below I have posted my nested JSON response. I want to get all the keys and key values to load into one tableview like below UI. Please help me!

My JSON

```
response : {

     ANI =  { 
             name = "anisharmu";
             age  = "10";
     };

     ROC =  { 
             name = "rockins";
             age  = "20";   
     };
}
```

MY UI Tableview

```
|------------------------|
  ANI anisharmu - 10
|------------------------|
```

My Code

```
 NSError *error;
 jsonDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
 // get keys from response dictionary
 NSMutableArray * key = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[jsonDictionary[@"response"] allKeys]];

 // sort as asending order
 NSSortDescriptor* sortOrder = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey: @"self" ascending: YES];
 key =  (NSMutableArray *)[key sortedArrayUsingDescriptors: [NSArray arrayWithObject: sortOrder]];

 // access inner data from dictonary
 for (NSString * obj in key) {

            NSLog(@"%@",jsonDictionary[@"response"][obj][@"name"]);

 }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Populate UITableView with NSDictionary JSON in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28852192/populate-uitableview-with-nsdictionary-json-in-swift)

Comment: I need Objective C code...@whirlwind

Comment: maybe you can try with this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21207359/populate-uitableview-with-json-array

Answer (score 0):

the response here is a dictionary.

If you are using `AFNetworking` then simply access the response as a `NSDictionary`. You can get the values by accessing their keys.

`NSDictionary  *aniDict =[ responseDict objectForKey:@"ANI"];` will return the object under the `ANI` key.

Access the new dictionary for nested dictionaries as well.

```
NSString *name = [aniDict valueForKey:@"name"];
int age =  [[aniDict objectForKey:@"age"] integerValue];
```

Numbers and bools are `NSSNumber` instances within dictionaries and need to be unwrapped.

Comment: Please need sample code. Its urgent! @Vendetta Turkey

Comment: But NSDictionary giving UNorder outputs

Comment: NSDictionary is mostly a map, you can access objects regardless of order!!! in your question get a little bit more organised. provide how you get the response. you ask people for code samples and you didn't even provide how your request is being fetched.

Answer (score 0):

**Parse the response data first like below:**

```
NSData *responseData;
        NSError *error;
        NSDictionary *jSONDictonary = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

        NSArray *allKeys = [jSONDictonary allKeys];
```

**Then write the below code in your cellforRowAtIndexpath method:**

```
cell.mainName.text  = [allKeys objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];
    cell.namelabel.text = [jSONDictonary valueForKeyPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.name",[allKeys objectAtIndex:indexpath.row]]];
    cell.ageLabel.text  = [jSONDictonary valueForKeyPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.age",[allKeys objectAtIndex:indexpath.row]]];
```

Comment: Its. making crash -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 3 beyond bounds [0 .. 2]' @Vikram

Comment: Its not getting name values @vikram

Comment: can you please add your code for me here. So that i can have a look

Comment: U can see my above code. but its not working out of conditions.

Comment: did you understand anything?

Answer (score 0):

contact your script maker and call him to make script like this

```
     response : [

                 {  
                     id=ANI;
                     name = "anisharmu";
                     age  = "10";

                  }

              {      id =ROC;  
                     name = "rockins";
                     age  = "20";
              }
                  ];
        }
    NSMutableArray *ArrData=[responseDict objecforKeys:@"response"];//all data in array now just put it in your tableview
    int i=[ArrData count];//all keys



- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView

{

    return 1;

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

{

    return [ArrData count];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

    NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell %ld",(long)indexPath.row];



    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];



    cell = nil;

    if (cell == nil)

    {

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        UILabel *lbl_id=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 40)];
        lbl_id.text = [[ArrData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"id"];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl_id];
        lbl_id.layer.borderColor=[UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
        lbl_id.layer.borderWidth=4.0;
        [lbl_id release];

        UILabel *lblName=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 40, 100, 40)];
        lblName.text = [[ArrData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:lblName];
        lblName.layer.borderColor=[UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
        lblName.layer.borderWidth=4.0;

        [lblName release];

        UILabel *lblage=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 70, 100, 40)];
        lblage.text=[[ArrData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"age"];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:lblage];
        lblage.layer.borderColor=[UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
        [lblage release];



    }



    return cell;

}
```

Comment: Ok Thank you @Kandhal

Comment: now do like this there are problem with your JSON output which is never display output that you like to get .....say your script maker to do like this

Comment: reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b6385a0' Crashing

Comment: Your JSON structure is something like this:

Dictionary-->Array-->Object (Dictionary).

So you need to do:

Extract the Array from the dictionary using the key response
Extract an object(Dictionary) from the array using the index
Get the name from the dictionary object using the key name
its simple yar

Comment: First thing U have modified My JSON response. Please check above what I am posted please.